# Is there any http monitor for intellij idea GUI? Like the one in Netbeans?

Tags: intellij-idea, netbeans, monitoring, sniffer

I am a netbeans user, now I want to switch to Intellij IDEA.

But I can't find any working http monitor in Intellij IDEA GUI like the one in Netbeans. I want to use the http monitor to see the requests in Tomcat.

I have tried the plugin Axis Tcp monitor, it keeps saying Address already in use:JVM_Bind.

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [TunnelliJ](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=155) plug-in.

Comment: Seems to be dead. Also, only provides information which one can get from the browser itself. I would be more interested in monitoring Tomcat sessions, their sizes, objects in the session etc, which no tunneling plugin can provide.

Comment: I found TunnelliJ sometimes worked and sometimes did not.  I ended up uninstalling it and am now using AXIS TCP Monitor instead.

Comment: Ok i'm on a rant about I fnd Intellij's support in this area being flawed.  Axis TCP Monitor has no documentation.  This TunnelliJ plugin says "General Usage Instructions - https://github.com/milanboruvka/tunnellij", which is great but that page links back to the plugin page.  Bloody developers.  Do you know how many projects I've worked on where I needed to modify existing code but there was NO DOCUMENTATION.  Far too many!  No unit tests either in most of these cases also.  <end_rant/>

Comment: Just to complete my thoughts ... TunnelliJ does have an entry under the help menu of IntelliJ that will open the plugin pane.  However I couldn't get it to work.  I hit play and run the code that makes an HTTP call (I confirmed by looking at Wireshark) and nothing is displayed.  Do you need to try and work out the IP / DNS and/or PORT?

Answer (score 3):

You can also consider [Axis TCP Monitor](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/154?pr=idea). I prefer it over TunnelliJ because it has XML Format option, which allows you to read xml request/response objects from the IDE itself.

Comment: How the tiny-tanks do you use that.  There is NO documentation and the only ref to any kind of documentation seems to be Apache Axis but I don't know if that is the same thing.  It only seems to be for Soap.  But i may be wrong.  Such simple use cases surrounding "what http requests are coming from my code out of IntelliJ".  This shouldn't be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you will not stick to `Intellij Idea` tools/plugins and allow usage of external tools, I suggest to give a try to `Telerik Fiddler 4`:

https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Among other things it could decrypt ssl traffic setting own certificate.